# How to check if the start and end time that you want to plan for an activity aren't already planned?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I need to make a query that checks if the start and endtime that a user wants to plan something aren't already planned

I currently have this query:

```
select *
from planned_activities
where 
    user_id = 161
and
    '2022-01-11 17:36:00' between start_time and end_time
or '2022-01-11 18:36:00' between start_time and end_time
or ('2022-01-11 17:36:00' <= start_time and '2022-01-13 18:36:00' >= end_time);
```

I find it hard to explain but I basicly want to return the data from the other planned activity if the planning isn't possible.

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and make a [mre]

Comment: Please have a read through the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider adding a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with suitable sample data and desired results

Comment: Consider using the [Application time periods without overlaps](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/application-time-periods/#without-overlaps) feature of MariaDB. With these constraints you can insert and catch an exception to determine conflicts. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70617518/how-to-query-to-return-data-range-between-start-date-and-end-date/70617610#70617610) on detecting overlaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                FROM planned_activities
                WHERE @current_user_id = planned_activities.user_id 
                  AND @planned_activity_start < planned_activities.end_time
                  AND @planned_activity_end > planned_activities.start_time ) row_exists
```

The query checks does the row for current user which overlaps with entered time range exists. Returns one row with one column `row_exists`, possible values are 1 (the overlapping is found) or 0 (entered time range is free).

If adjacent time ranges are not allowed too then use weak comparing operators.